# Accessing Sub class member from base class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop, inheritance

i tried to access the subclass member variable from base class. But i can't access it. It returns a null value..

for eg..

I have baseclass classA and Subclass ClassB. i tried to access the classB member variable say x from base class ClassA. but it returns null. i assigned classB variable with some value.

i tried like this..

```
In classA.h

@classB

@property (nonatomic, retain) classB *BObj;


In classA.m


#import classB.h

@synthesize BObj;

BObj = [[classB alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%d",BObj.x); //returns NULL


In ClassB.h

@interface ClassB :ClassA

@property(nonatomic,retain) int x;

In ClassB.m

@synthesize x;

x = 10; //This value should be read from super class(Class A).
```

Comment: Your code is not at all syntactically valid. Anyone who wants to help is going to have to play 20 Questions to solve this if you won't give us real code to look at.

Comment: @chuck: i pasted the above code which is the copy of my actual code. i just replaced with classA and classB. That's All. can you provide me an example to access the subclass object's value from base class..

Comment: Nope, that won't compile either.

Answer (score 2):

As Chuck says in comments, this doesn't look like real code. Where are you setting x to 10? If it isn't in your init method, or in a method called from init, it won't display. And you have invalidated your complaint with your edit - logging %d will not show null, it will show zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : NSLog(@"%d", BObj.x);

Comment: oh..thanks..but the pblm is not with that..it's not giving any warning or Error.it simply print the NULL value

Comment: Indeed, this is because the syntax is correct. Your NSLog is equivalent to NSLog(@"%@", BObj.x); The %@ means you want to print a complex object. In this case, this is not an object but a simple integer.